# Cannot convert Jobject type to a Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>

Tags: c#, json, json.net, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

How can I convert a `JObject` to a `Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>`.
I tried this way

```
data.ToObject<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>>()
```

but it gives me error saying  *""Error converting value "123" to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.EntityProperty'. Path 'Version'."}"*

How can I do this?
**data** on debugging gives me this structure:

```
{
  "Version": "123",
  "Eest": {
    "Bulls": 1848,
    "Message": "Passed (0.325 mA < 2[0] => 'P')",
    "Credit": 0.325,
    "Read": 0.14,
    "SBin": "P"
  },
  "GenericTests": [],
  "HostVersion": "Test",
  "RawSampleIDData": [
    1,
    3,
    2,
    4
  ]
}
```

Comment: [`EntityProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.entityproperty?view=azure-dotnet) is a *Class for storing information about a single property in an entity in a table.*.  Why do you think Json.NET should be able to deserialize a primitive value such as `"123"` to this type?  Is there a `JsonConverter<EntityProperty>` somewhere?  See [Convert DynamicTableEntity to Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975107/3744182): *Unfortunately, DynamicTableEntity and EntityProperty are not serializable currently.*

Comment: Also the value of `"Eest"` is a **JSON obejct** not a primitive value so even if you implemented a custom `JsonConverter<EntityProperty>` you would not be able to store the value of `"Eest"` in it since `EntityProperty` seems to only represent a primitive value.

Comment: I am assuming that your `EntityProperty` is a [`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.EntityProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.entityproperty?view=azure-dotnet).  If not please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing this type.

Comment: yes its cosmos.table.entityProperty. can you please post your answer in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot deserialize the JSON object shown in your question to a `Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>` even with a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).**  This is because [`EntityProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.entityproperty?view=azure-dotnet) is a *Class for storing information about a single property in an entity in a table.*  As such, it can capture a variety of .Net primitives [including](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.edmtype?view=azure-dotnet):

- `byte []`
- `bool`
- `DateTime`.
- `double`, `int` and `long`.
- `string`

However, your root JSON object's values included nested arrays (`"RawSampleIDData"`) and objects (`"Eest"`).  As such, it cannot be deserialized to a dictionary of `EntityProperty` primitives.  You will need to adopt a different data model to deserialize that JSON.

Relatedly, see:

- *[insert complex objects to azure table with TableServiceEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19885219/3744182)*.

**If your object values were entirely JSON primitives**, you could introduce the following converter:

```
public class EntityPropertyConverter : JsonConverter<EntityProperty>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, EntityProperty value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.PropertyAsObject);

    public override EntityProperty ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, EntityProperty existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
                return null;
            case JsonToken.Integer:
                if (reader.Value is int i)
                    return new EntityProperty(i);
                else if (reader.Value is long l)
                    return new EntityProperty(l);
                // BigInteger not supported.
                break;
            case JsonToken.Float:
                if (reader.Value is double d)
                    return new EntityProperty(d);
                else if (reader.Value is decimal m)
                    return new EntityProperty((double)m);
                break;
            case JsonToken.String:
                return new EntityProperty((string)reader.Value);
            case JsonToken.Boolean:
                return new EntityProperty((bool)reader.Value);
            case JsonToken.Date:
                if (reader.Value is DateTime dt)
                    return new EntityProperty(dt);
                else if (reader.Value is DateTimeOffset dto)
                    return new EntityProperty(dto);
                break;
            case JsonToken.Bytes:
                if (reader.Value is byte [] a)
                    return new EntityProperty(a);
                else if (reader.Value is Guid g)
                    return new EntityProperty(g);
                break;
        }
        throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Cannot convert value {0} to {1}", reader.TokenType, nameof(EntityProperty)));
    }       
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new EntityPropertyConverter() },
};
var dict = data.ToObject<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>>(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m3fUXR).

**Update**

With the above converter, one option to deserialize an arbitrary `JObject` to a `Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>` would be to flatten the object to a dictionary keyed by the [path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Path.htm) of each primitive values, like so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new EntityPropertyConverter() },
};
var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
var dict = data.Descendants().OfType<JValue>().ToDictionary(v => v.Path, v => v.ToObject<EntityProperty>(serializer));
```

For the JSON in the question the result is

```json
{
  "Version": "123",
  "Eest.Bulls": 1848,
  "Eest.Message": "Passed (0.325 mA < 2[0] => 'P')",
  "Eest.Credit": 0.325,
  "Eest.Read": 0.14,
  "Eest.SBin": "P",
  "HostVersion": "Test",
  "RawSampleIDData[0]": 1,
  "RawSampleIDData[1]": 3,
  "RawSampleIDData[2]": 2,
  "RawSampleIDData[3]": 4
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3bBKC1).